# What is the best practice for REST API design when an element does not exist in the DB?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, api-design

I am building a REST API. To retrieve a specific product, there is an API endpoint:

```
GET /product/{product-id}
```

This endpoint returns `200` with the response body. However, currently, I am returning the status `200` with the body as null when `product-id` does not exist. What should be the response code actually? Is returning `200` is ok?

Example:

product with ID `100`, `101`, `102`, `103` exist is my service.

```
GET /product/100 -> returns json response with status code as 200
GET /product/101 -> returns json response with status code as 200
GET /product/102 -> returns json response with status code as 200
GET /product/103 -> returns json response with status code as 200
```

But there is no product with ID `999` in this service. What's the response code?

```
GET /product/999 -> what should be the response code for this case?
```

This is a very fundamental question for building a basic REST CRUD application. And now I see I don't understand what should be the response code!

I would appreciate it if someone can guide me what is the best practice considering the best practices for REST API design.

Comment: @pzaenger it does not answer the question. That question was for a user-facing page and this is related to what is the best practice for a REST API.

Comment: I think, returning a `404` is suitable. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868596/restful-ajax-which-http-status-code-for-item-not-found); or [this](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) for `GET` a specific Item (e.g. `/customers/{id})`: _`200` (OK), single customer. `404` (Not Found), if ID not found or invalid._

Comment: @pzaenger again its a user facing app and `404` makes sense. But I am wondering what should I do considering  best practices for REST API design.

Comment: Both links are about REST and the [last one](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) is explicit about CRUD operations.

Comment: REST = HTTP, user facing pages are HTTP. In HTTP you return 404 if a resource does not exist.